# C# mongodb creating group with switch case using BSON document qry

Tags: .net, mongodb, bson

How do you create a BSON qry using BSONDocuments. I am trying to use a group by qry with a switch case clause in dotNet.  My goal is to be able to create BSON queries based on some minimal configurations - the configuration that produces the qry below would look something like: State,City,Branch(State=NY,State!=NY) - using .net, I would traverse the configuration and create a BSON query on my data Here is the query in pure BSON - that can be run in Mongo shell:

```
db.test_collection.aggregate([
 {
 $group: {
    "_id": {
        X: "$State",
        Y_DT: "$City",
    Z: {   $switch: {
          branches: [
                 { case: { $eq: [ "$State", "NY" ] }, then: "equals" },
                 { case: { $ne: [ "$State", "NY" ] }, then: "equals" }
              ]
           }
        }
        },
    adj: {"$sum": 1}
    }
    } 
]
      )
```

I am trying to add the third piece of the group (the switch/branches section) to .net code below

Here is my .net code so far:

```
BsonDocument pipelineStage1 = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$group", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {
                        "_id", new BsonArray
                        {
                            {
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "state", "$State" }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "city", "$City" }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                new BsonDocument()      //want to add switch/case statement here
                            }

                        }


                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "count", new BsonDocument{
                            { "$sum" , 1}
                        }
                    }
                }
             }}
```

so far the .net code works but I need to add the section indicated above

Comment: If you unsure how to write the BsonDocument syntax, you can use MongoDB Compass to help you generate: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/export-query-to-language/